# How to execute a bash-script from a java script

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I would like to share GitHub actions between some of my repositories which now contain a release bash script in each repository.

In order to be able to run the same script, I need a Github Action in order to do that.

I have little knowledge of javascript and am unable to rewrite the simple hello world javascript action (https://github.com/actions/hello-world-javascript-action/blob/master/index.js) to run a bash script.

The idea of using a javascript as an action is preferred because of its performance and providing access to The GitHub webhook payload.

My first attempt of providing a javascript action based on the hello-world action:

```
const exec = require('@actions/exec');
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');

try {
  const filepath = core.getInput('file-path');
  console.log(`testing ${filepath`});

  // Get the JSON webhook payload for the event that triggered the workflow
  const payload = JSON.stringify(github.context.payload, undefined, 2);
  console.log(`The event payload: ${payload}`);

  exec.exec('./test')
} catch (error) {
  core.setFailed(error.message);
}
```

How do I execute the javascript from the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how one can execute a bash script from a javascript action. Script-file is `index.js`

```
const core = require("@actions/core");
const exec = require("@actions/exec");
const github = require("@actions/github");

async function run() {
  try {
    // Set the src-path
    const src = __dirname + "/src";
    core.debug(`src: ${src}`);

    // Fetch the file path from input
    const filepath = core.getInput("file-path");
    core.debug(`input: ${filepath}`);

    // Execute bash script
    await exec.exec(`${src}/test`);

    // Get the JSON webhook payload for the event that triggered the workflow
    const payload = JSON.stringify(github.context.payload, undefined, 2);
    console.debug(`github event payload: ${payload}`);

  } catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message);
  }
}

// noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall
run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only possible [types of actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/about-actions#types-of-actions) are Javascript and Docker container actions.

So your options are either:

1. Execute the bash script in a Docker container action
2. Execute the bash script from a Javascript action. The [`@actions/exec`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/master/packages/exec) package of the [`actions/toolkit`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit) is designed to do exactly this—execute tools and scripts.

Comment: I would really appreciate an example of how to execute a script using @actions/exec

Comment: In future, please don't change the question and retract the accept answer. If you have a follow-up problem you should make a new question. If I have some time I'll try and make an example using `@actions/exec`. In the meantime you can check [this code](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request/blob/master/index.js) where I'm using a Javascript action to execute Python.