# How to pass GitHub action event hook from a javascript to a bash file?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to create a GitHub action that is simple and only run a bash-script file, see previous
question: [How to execute a bash-script from a java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976112/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-from-a-java-script)

With this javascript action, I want to pass values to the bash-script from the JSON payload given by GitHub.

Can this be done with something as simple as an exec command?

```
    ...
    exec.exec(`export FILEPATH=${filepath}`)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do something like this, but found there to be much more code needed that I originally expected. So while this is not simple, it does work and will block the action script while the bash script runs:

```
const core = require('@actions/core');

function run() {
  try {
    // This is just a thin wrapper around bash, and runs a file called "script.sh"
    // 
    // TODO: Change this to run your script instead
    // 
    const script = require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'script.sh');

    var child = require('child_process').execFile(script);
    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    child.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
      process.exit(code);
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message);
  }
}

run()
```

Much of the complication is handling output and error conditions.

You can see my [debugger-action](https://github.com/csexton/debugger-action) repo for an example.